# How can I add drag n Drop functionality in image android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-imageview

I have three buttons in the main XML which contain add a table, and chair, reset.when I clicked add table it will add a table in second layout same for add chair.I want to move both images after adding in the second layout just like Drag and Drop.

Main activity which contains three buttons.on each button click, it will pass to second.java through intent

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ArrayList<String> mSelecetdItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public static final String SELECETD_ITEMS = "SELECETD_ITEMS";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    public  void addtable(View v){
        this.mSelecetdItems.add("table");
        showSecondActivity();
    }
    public  void addchair(View v){
        this.mSelecetdItems.add("chair");
        showSecondActivity();
    }


    private void showSecondActivity()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Second.class);
        i.putStringArrayListExtra(SELECETD_ITEMS,this.mSelecetdItems);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList(SELECETD_ITEMS , mSelecetdItems);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        this.mSelecetdItems = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(SELECETD_ITEMS);
    }


activity_main.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.andiroot.restaurantbook.MainActivity">




    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ff1e8622"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="64dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_addtbl"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
            android:text="Add Table"
            android:onClick="addtable"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_addchairs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="addchair"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Add Chair"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_addtbl"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_addtbl" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_addchairs"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_addchairs"
            android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
            android:text="Reset" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


Second.java



public class Second extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.second_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        /*toolbar.setNavigationIcon((R.drawable.back_arrow));

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });*/


        LinearLayoutCompat hall = (LinearLayoutCompat) findViewById(R.id.hall_layout);
        Intent i = getIntent();


        ArrayList<String> selecetdItems = i.getStringArrayListExtra(MainActivity.SELECETD_ITEMS);
        for (String selecetdItem : selecetdItems) {
            if (selecetdItem.equals("table")) {
                addImageView(R.drawable.table, hall);
            } else if (selecetdItem.equals("chair")) {
                addImageView2(R.drawable.chair2, hall);
            }
        }


    }

    private void addImageView(int imageRes, LinearLayoutCompat hall) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageResource(imageRes);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(250, 250));
        iv.setMaxHeight(180);
        iv.setMaxWidth(120);
        iv.setPadding(15,15,0,0);
        hall.addView(iv);
    }

    private void addImageView2(int imageRes, LinearLayoutCompat hall) {
        ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(this);
        iv2.setImageResource(imageRes);
        iv2.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        iv2.setMaxHeight(30);
        iv2.setMaxWidth(30);

        iv2.setPadding(25,0,0,0);
        hall.addView(iv2);
    }

activity_second.java


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/hall_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.andiroot.restaurantbook.Second">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/second_toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ff1e8622"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<!--
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/hall_layout2">
    </RelativeLayout>
-->
</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement onTouchListener on those images.

```
  @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
int width=cropperLayout.getLayoutParams().width;;
    int height=cropperLayout.getLayoutParams().height;
    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            dX = v.getX() - event.getRawX();
            dY = v.getY() - event.getRawY();

            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            if (width == windowWidth && height == windowHeight){}
            else {
                v.animate()
                        .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                        .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                        .setDuration(0)
                        .start();

                if (event.getRawX() + dX + width > windowWidth) {
                    v.animate()
                            .x(windowWidth - width)
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();
                }
                if (event.getRawX() + dX < 0) {
                    v.animate()
                            .x(0)
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();
                }
                if (event.getRawY() + dY + height > windowHeight) {
                    v.animate()
                            .y(windowHeight - height)
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();
                }
                if (event.getRawY() + dY < 0) {
                    v.animate()
                            .y(0)
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();
                }

                return true;
            }    
  }
  }
```

Comment: can you give me some example?

Comment: like you would have implimented onClickListeners on the button in the same way just do it on the images. like image.setOnTouchListener(New OnTouchListener) like this

Comment: sorry about that, change public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) { to public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

Comment: you need to try it yourself, i have told you the solution, just implement it.